# How to stop a \ from closing a string

Tags: python, file, python-3.4, definition

I need to open a file in a folder and this should work but the \ causes the string to close so the Me variable is green when it should not me. How can I fix it, I need to be able to stop \ from closing the string or direct into a folder without using the \ symbol. Most the variable I used seem random, this is because I do not want it to be similar to real functions to get it mixed up confusing me or others.

```
Me = Jacob #Variable me with Jacob in it
def God():#creates function called god
    File = open ("Test\" + Me + ".txt","r")#opens the Jacob file in the test folder.
    Door = ""#creates door variable
    Door = File.read().splitlines()#sets what is in Jacob file to be in Door variable
    print (Door)#prints the varible door
God()#does go function
```

Comment: Use forward slash in file paths. It will make things easier.

Comment: "the \ causes the string to close" In fact, the problem is the opposite: the string **doesn't** end where the `"` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
"Test\\"
```

Or simply use a forward slash `"Test/"`

You can also let `os.path.join` take care of joining your path:

```
import os

pth = os.path.join("Test", "{}.txt".format(Me))

with open(pth) as f:
     Door = f.readlines()
```

I also recommend using `with` to open your files and if you want a list of lines you can call `readlines`, if you really want the newlines removed you can call `map` on the file object  or use a list comp:

```
 with open(pth) as f:
     Door = list(map(str.rstrip, f))
```

Or:

```
     Door = [ln.rstrip() for ln in f]
```

Comment: What about raw strings?

Comment: @PeterWood,   it  would not actually work in the OP's case, you would get a syntaxError.